# The redirect_uri does not match the registered value Azure AD B2C For LinkedIn

Tags: azure, uri, linkedin-api, azure-ad-b2c

I tried to add an identity provider for my Azure AD B2C, I add Facebook and LinkedIn for my Azure AD B2C provider. Facebook is working fine but not LinkedIn it keep getting error like this:

> The redirect_uri does not match the registered value

Here is my redirect uri:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/Heisenberg.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp
```

As you can see `Heisenber.onmicrosoft.com` is my tenant. I also tried the following redirect uri:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com
```

The result is the same.

Any suggestion what should I do or change?

Comment: Try to add "/signin-linkedin" at the end of the uri like this: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/Heisenberg.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp/signin-linkedin`

Comment: Can you sign out of LinkedIn, and then click "LinkedIn" in your policy. When it sends the request to LinkedIn, you can look at the URL in the browser and see what "redirect_uri" is passed in. It must match the redirect_uri that is registered for your application. If you have difficulty with that, please update the question with the link for the authentication page at LinkedIn.

Comment: fixed, what should i do is , i must use lower case to my redirect uri, even tough my tenant is Heisenberg.onmicrosoft.com with capital. So i tried to change to all lower case and its worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fixed, what should i do is , i must use lower case to my redirect uri, even tough my tenant is Heisenberg.onmicrosoft.com with capital. So i tried to change to all lower case and its worked

Comment: I have standalone java application that has to connect to LinkedIn Marketing Campains API and upload contact list. Where is the URL i have to configure in website and redirect URL of LinkedIn app creation process?